# Subscript spacing in newtxmath (comma issue)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations, subscripts, newtxmath

I've found a strange behavior of `newtxmath` package. Using my code with `documentclass[12pt]`all commas are glued to the next letter, which can be hard to read: [image: 12 pt]

When I change`documentclass[11pt]` everything looks very nice:
[image: 11pt]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Q_i=Q_{inf,i}+Q_{vent,i}+Q_{g,c,i}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Could someone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following pictures explain the problem, which should brought to the attention of the package maintainer. The comma in the math letters font (family 1) has a wrong bounding box

### With `newtxmath`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
% draw a tight bounding box with hairline rules
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{$,$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Without `newtxmath`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
% draw a tight bounding box with hairline rules
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{$,$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Workaround

Use the comma from the text font

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"2C}                  
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Q_i=Q_{inf,i}+Q_{vent,i}+Q_{g,c,i}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's definitely an issue with an incorrect bounding box for the math comma of the newtxmath package. Is there maybe a secondary anomaly present as well, since the awful comma positioning happens only at `12pt` but not at `11pt` or `10pt`?

Comment: @Mico Indeed! The font used is `rtxmi.pfb` with the `12pt` class option, but `rtxmi7.pfb` with the `10pt` or `11pt` options. The bounding box drawing was created with the `12pt` option, that I forgot to add.

Comment: @egreg your answer solve my problem. Thank you! In the meantime I've found another workaround. I does not repair bounding box but makes the equation looks fine, using `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`

Comment: @MichaelSharpe have you seen this?